# Mapping fields of constructor parameter object from src

Tags: c#, stream, automapper

I'm trying to map object contains ctor parameter which fields I need to set from src object (From `Image` class to `ImageDownloadResponse` class):

```
public class Image
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public byte[] ImageData { get; set; }
    public string ImageMimeType { get; set; }
}

public class ImageDownloadResponse
{
    public ImageDownloadResponse(ImageMetaData metaData, Stream stream)
    {
        DownloadedImageMetadata = metaData;
        ImageByteStream = stream;
    }
    public ImageMetaData DownloadedImageMetadata;
    public Stream ImageByteStream;
}

public class ImageMetaData
{
    public ImageMetaData(Guid imageId, string imageMimeType)
    {
        ImageId = imageId;
        ImageMimeType = imageMimeType;
    }
    public Guid ImageId;
    public string ImageMimeType;
}
```

Here's what I got in mapping (not valid code 'cause I can not construct a new object in after option parameter):

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Image, ImageDownloadResponse>()
    .ConstructUsing(x => new ImageDownloadResponse(new ImageMetaData(x.Id, x.ImageMimeType), Stream.Null ))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.DownloadedImageMetadata,
                opt => new ImageMetaData(opt.MapFrom(src => src.Id), opt.MapFrom(src => src.ImageMimeType)))
    .AfterMap((image, response) =>
    {
        response.ImageByteStream = new MemoryStream(image.ImageData);
    });
```

Also I don't sure that using `AfterMap` for setting stream from byte array is really good. Could someone correct my way of mapping these objects?

Comment: Automapper is a great tool, when you have a lot of properties to map and they can be mapped *automatically*. That's why it is called "Automapper". Your code has a bit of data to map, and a huge piece of mapper's config. There's no any benefit from Automapper here. Why don't throw it away?

Comment: Want to clear code in main methods of my project.. Also there are not really huge classes. Just need to build inner object first, then take two properties from src to set them and one property for main class.